# jQuery resizable issue if applied to child element of a resizable

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-resizable

Here is my complete code, which is derived from [jQuery Resizable Example](http://jqueryui.com/resizable/) -

In my example I have two `div` elements, with id `parent` and `child`, where `child` element is inside `parent` element. My Problem is I am not able to resize `parent` element, even I have made it `resizable`. Has anyone faced the similar issue?

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>jQuery UI Resizable - Default functionality</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>

  <style>
  #parent {
    padding: 40px;
    width:400px;
    height:400px;
  }

  #child { 
    width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
  }

  </style>
  <script>
  $(function() {    
    $( "#child" ).resizable();
    $( "#parent" ).resizable();
  });
  </script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="parent" class="ui-widget-content">
  <h3>Parent</h3>
    <div id="child" class="ui-widget-content">
        <h3>Child</h3>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

**NOTE**

Playing with the code, I just found out, this problem only occur is I make `child` element reseizable before `parent` element. As in code -

```
  $(function() {    
    $( "#child" ).resizable();
    $( "#parent" ).resizable();
  });
```

If I change the order  to -

```
  $(function() {    
    $( "#parent" ).resizable();
    $( "#child" ).resizable();
  });
```

it will work smoothly. I am not sure why it is happening.

I will try looking into jQuery resizable code but if someone already have faced and solve this issue it will be very helpful.

-Thanks

Comment: May be related to this.. ? http://bugs.jqueryui.com/ticket/5155

Comment: @kameswarib Thanks, but I am not able to relate it with my problem. Contrary to the description in the defect, in my case child does not lose resizability, but parent does.

Answer (score 1):

A ticket has been opened about this [on jQuery bugtracker (ticket #7711)](http://bugs.jqueryui.com/ticket/7711), but as you can see, it was considered has "not a bug", specifying the work-around you found by yourself as a solution:

> *As a work-around, initialize the outer/parent resizable first and both are resizable*